# Enabling disabling checkboxes in a datatable

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, xhtml

Is there a way in Primefaces to enable or disable a checkbox in a datatable? Right now my datatable is like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="dTable" var="tt" value="#{aBean.aList}" selection="#{aBean.selectedValue}" rowStyleClass="#{tt.state.intValue() le 1 ? 'active' : 'passive'}">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
    ...
</dataTable>
```

but this code just puts a column with checkboxes together with a checkbox in the header. I want checkboxes to be rendered according to a value in the backing bean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FWIW many years later...

In PF 5.x you know longer do this in the column, you have to set up a `disabledSelection` criteria in the `<p:datatable ...>` tag.

Something like :

```
<p:datatable disabledSelection="#{myvar ne null}" ... >
```

This took me quite a bit to figure out since often questions (everywhere) are posed and answered without regards to version.  Here is where I finally found the answer.

[Optimus Prime's response on PF Community Forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38042)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes you're right, I should've given the version.. Now you have provided the answer acc to new version, I have selected your answer as the right answer.

Comment: @lamostreta   Thank you!  That's my first. :-)    I wasn't really calling you out on that, TBH.  It's true everywhere which seems weird with some 3 major versions in use.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution inside PF here: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14029 
Usage of rowstyleclass and css solved the problem:

xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="dTable" var="tt" value="#{aBean.aList}" 
                                  selection="#{aBean.selectedValue}" rowStyleClass="#{tt.state.intValue() le 1 ? 'active' : 'passive'}">                    

<p:column    selectionMode="multiple"/>
...
</dataTable>
```

css:

```
.active{    
    background-image: none !important;   
}

.passive{
    background-color:gainsboro !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.passive td.ui-selection-column input {
       display:none;
    }
```

This enables/disables command button using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

try out the `disabledSelection` of the `<p:column`

You can always do it without the  , just do it manually... by placing

And you can make use of the

> rowIndexVar : Name of iterator to refer each row index.

for referring the row number

And here is how the selection column should look like (more or less)

used the `checkall` class in order to delegate it later on using jQuery and do the `select all magic`

```
<p:column id="selection_column">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="" class="checkall"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox rendered="#{myRow.selectable}" value="#{myRow.selected}"/>
</p:column>



jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery(document).delegate(".checkall", "click", function(event) {
        jQuery(this).closest("table").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am using PF 2.2.1 and p:column does not have this attribute..

Comment: than you can always do it without the <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/> , just do it manually... by placing <h:selectBooleanCheckbox inside of the <p:column (ofcourse a bit more of coding will be needed)... I'm not aware of other way... a JSF + jQuery solution fits you?

Comment: thanks again.. this works. but this time I can not pass the selected row to backing bean.. I need to find a workaround for this..

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I found the solution inside the scope of PF without using JS..